# How to find videos using the YouTube API based on a channel ID

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels

So I am playing around with the YouTube API v3 for a web app I am building. I've got the basics down, but I am searching through documentation trying to find a way to filter a returned video list based on a channelID. However this doesn't seem to be possible. Is there way to write a request similar to this pseudocode below:

```
   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&

   // and a second value that would imply with channelID=UCn8zNIfYAQNdrFRrr8oibKw
```

This seems like a logical function to have in the API. However, I can't seem to find any name/value pair in the documentation to support this theory.

The closest I can seem to find is the onBehalfOfContentOwner name/value pair for the video.list request (but it requires me to be the uploader of the video?) as [outlined here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

Anyways if someone can answer definitively if this is possible (if yes a link to docs or example I can use) as I've poured over docs looking for this functionality with no luck. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your link refers to a video search.

1) First, you need to retrieve the channel info for the channelID (e.g. UCn8zNIfYAQNdrFRrr8oibKw).

```
See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels
Get the part:
```

"contentDetails": {
  "relatedPlaylists": {
      "likes": string,
      "favorites": string,
      "uploads": string,
      "watchHistory": string,
      "watchLater": string
  }

2) Then use the "uploads": string, to retrieve the videos, being the user uploaded videos, which is a playlist.

For retrieving playlists see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists .

Answer (score 1):

Use the api call `search.list`, for example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=ASADKAHWSDA&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

in the query parameters specified the resource `type = video` because you want the videos of this channel. As cited here https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list

> The type parameter restricts a search query to only retrieve a particular type of resource. The value is a comma-separated list of resource types. (string)

The resource can be anything a video, playlist, subscriber, etc. Hope this help.